# Best way to integrate user defined function

Tags: matlab, integral

I would like to evaluate an expression which requires an integral of a user defined function.
I have 3 inputs to the integral expression, E,F and B.  F and B are values stored in separate arrays. E is the parameter I would like to integrate over, from a value of 0 to the value of B.
  I am trying to use the integral function with a user defined function, although I keep getting a matrix dimension error, which I do not comprehend as all the values for F, B (I thought) are being passed as scalar inputs.

However, I realize that for each iteration of the loop I am defining a new function, this seems "inelegant".  Any advice as to 
1. Why it will not run as is (i.e. the error using *, inner matrix dimensions must agree)
2. Any more elegant solution?

Here is the loop

```
     for i=1:51
               % DEFINE energy integrand, without prefixes
               nrgInt=@(E,F,B) sqrt(E)*exp(-8*pi*(m*q)^(0.5)*(B-E)/(3*h*F))/(exp(E/(k*Temp))+1);
    % Integrate over energy range, store           
               J(i)=q*mu*8*pi*sqrt(2)*m.^1.5/h^3*Farray(1,i)*integral(@(E)nrgInt(E,Farray(1,i),Barray(i)),0,Barray(i));
               clear nrgInt
        end
```

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your 1st question, because `*` in Matlab represents matrix operator, so if not both sides of the operation are scalar, then both must have appropriate size, i.e `m-by-n matrix * n-by-p` matrix

For 2nd question, you can define the function seperately, then use vertorizing instead of for-loop:

```
J=q*mu*8*pi*sqrt(2)*m.^1.5/h^3*Farray(1,:)*integral(@(E)nrgInt(E,Farray(1,:),Barray(:)),0,Barray(:));
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand that * was for a matrix, but I thought I was passing only scalars to it. I'll go ahead with your solution, seems better, but am curious as to why it gave me the * error if E,F and B were scalars.

Comment: Hi again, this doesn't seem to work, and it seems to be tied to the integral function.  If I simply define my nrgInt and call it from the command line, it works fine, but if I try to integrate it, it gives me the * problem, even though I am NOT passing matrices.  How can I integrate my function?

`nrgInt = @(E,F,B) sqrt(E)*exp(-8*pi*(m*q)^(0.5)*(B-E)/(3*h*F))/(exp(E/(k*Temp))+1);`
`integral(@(E)nrgInt(E,0.1,1),0,1)
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.`

Comment: Nevermind, solution is less interesting than I thought.  Integral must use array operations by definition, I was trying to force matrix operations by using * instead of .* and / instead of ./.  RTFM to the rescue.